# using ZFS and local hard drives as a cache for a remote iSCSI SAN

Tags: amazon-ec2, zfs, iscsi, amazon-web-services

This is purely theoretical idea, i dont plan on doing this any time soon, but could you use Local hard drives as a kind of Cache to remote drives stored on Amazon EC2, shared to a user via iSCSI?

The idea i think is as follows:

- ZFS locally can use SSDs as a Read and Write cache
- mount a couple of "drives" as iSCSI, and add them to the ZFS pool as storage
- use a couple of local hard drives as read and write cache for the pool...

Now, i know you would need a fairly massive pipe between the Amazon data center and your office/house, but with the advent of Direct Connect, it could be plausable to get a 1 or 10Gb pipe to Amazon... But my question, could a remote iSCSI LUN be used in a ZFS pool, and would this work?

Comment: Why did someone down vote this? OK, so I don't have the bandwidth to use this every day or currently, but I could see this being a very handy feature, especially if you could get your EC2 drives backed up regularly...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, not sure what OS this is using, but Amazon have just announced [AWS Storage Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/?ref_=pe_12300_22527220) which does something simular to what i am thinking above...

- it creates a Virtual Machine on your network, which creates iSCSI volumes.
- it uses local storage for a "cache"
- it writes data back to S3 for snapshots and for backup...

Interesting idea, not free though. but should be interesting...

Comment: Current pricing on the gateway is $125/month base + storage charges - that's expensive for small volume stuff.  http://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/?ref_=pe_12300_22527220#pricing